# Форматирование текста в ответах

Tags: поддержка, форматирование, редактор

Есть странная особенность на сайте SO.

Когда пишешь каждое предложение с новой строки, то в результате это выглядит как будто пишешь предложения подряд.

И только если вставляешь дополнительную пустую строку между предложениями, то получается каждое предложение на отдельной строке.

То есть такое впечатление, что единичный <ВК-ПС> в тексте движок сайта фильтрует.

А когда <ВК-ПС> идут два подряд, то не фильтрует.

Это очень странно и неудобно.

Получается, что на сайте SO невозможно написать текст, в котором каждое предложение идет с новой строки, и между предложениями нет пустых строк.

Нельзя ли сделать как у всех нормальных людей, чтобы в соответствии с принципом WYSIWYG можно было бы делать форматирование текста так, как решил пользователь, а не так, как решил движок сайта.

Оказалось, что английские эквиваленты ВК-ПС движок сайта тоже фильтрует. Это тоже очень и очень странно.

Сейчас проверю совет насчет двух пробелов в конце строки.

Это предложение 1.
Это предложение 2.
Это предложение 3.

Действительно, работает.
А зачем так через сделано?

Comment: Дело привычки. Конечно, лучшим решением было, чтобы набор текста был WYSIWYG ..

Comment: @Kromster есть же превью при редактировании, неужели его недостаточно? А если вообще спрятать исходник и сделать только визивиг, то начнутся проблемы с форматирвованием. И в диффе непонятно, что показывать.

Comment: Pepsicoca1, пожалуйста, просто разбивайте текст на абзацы с помощью двойного переноса строки. Тогда между блоками текста есть промежуток и читателю понятно, что вот тут закончился один смысловой кусок текста и начался другой.

Comment: Если что, текст на сайте пишется в разметке Markdown и это поведение в точности соответствует спецификации Markdown. И там это тоже неспроста так сделано. Это позволяет разбивать длинные абзацы на много строк. Так исходник удобнее редактировать, а ещё `git diff` гораздо понятнее. Во многих языках программирования тоже рекомендуется выдерживать длину строки не больше каких-нибудь 80 или 100 символов. И синтаксис языка позволяет разбивать длинные строки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin есть то он есть, и это хорошо, но тем не менее костыль. Сделать в обычном редакторе перенос строки по Enter и отображение его с соответствующим отступом в 1,5 строки было бы лучше. А так лишний функционал как-то - Переном строки делается двумя переносами, а одинарный перенос обозначает пробел..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте два пробела в конце строки
и пишите с новой строки,
чтобы тескт был с новый строки
без вертикальных отступов.
Это не так и сложно.

Ещё с `<br>`
этого можно достичь.

---

Чтобы изменить это поведение на более простое (перенос строки без доп. условий) на главной мете был [feature request ещё с 2009 г](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26011/346987), но он сих пор без результата.

Comment: Действительно работает. Это не сложно, но более чем нетривиально. :-/

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Согласен, что нетривиально. Сам узнал не так давно. Но что поделаешь, такая платформа, так сделали переносы на новую строку.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, ещё `<br>` можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавил в ответ, спасибо, что напомнили.

Comment: Разрывать строку `<br>` (двумя пробелами) — плохая практика, так делать просто не нужно. В норме текст делится на абзацы, они разделяются двойным переносом строки.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin [текст делится на абзацы] С экрана очень удобно читать текст в котором каждое предложение начинается с новой строки. Раньше, во времена бумажной полиграфии, такая верстка была слишком расточительной из-за перерасхода бумаги. Теперь же, с приходом электронных документов, вполне можно оформлять текст так, чтобы каждое предложение начиналось с новой строки. Это очень удобно, так как позволяет не искать глазами продолжение текста на строке. А абзацы можно выделять пустыми строками. Попробуйте, и Вы увидите, что так гораздо удобнее читать да и писать.